# Change object material based on another object's location

Tags: shaders

I am playing with a scene where I have a treasure protected by a wireframe dome that gets attacked by airplanes. I would like my airplanes to change color when they get very close to the map and have them disappear when they try to go through the dome.

My idea was to use the Shading editor and based on the plane's location, change their color then make them become transparent. The issue that I'm having is that it is not only based on the airplane location but also on the dome's location. So here's my question: is there a way for me to use another object's information (i.e. the dome's location and radius) inside the Shading of an object (i.e. my airplane)? Or is there a better way to do this (without manually animating it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Object coordinates for this

1. Use Texture coordinates > Objects and target the dome
2. Use one ColorRamp for Base Color
3. Use another ColorRamp for alpha channel

[image]

Here a simple setup how you could realize it with two objects, which define the color of a third object:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know this changes color not material, but it's to keep it a bit simpler :)

Comment: Amazing! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help, good luck with your project ;)